# checking NSArray values

Tags: objective-c, arrays, if-statement

I have an NSArray (RSIatAddr), and I want to check whether the object at the given index = 0 (or some other arbitrary constant) but the following code gives me no warnings / error ; but is throwing an exception

```
if ([[RSIatAddr objectAtIndex:j] isEqualToNumber:nil]) {
    [sumRSI addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:[[RSIatAddr objectAtIndex:j]intValue]*
    [[sumRSI objectAtIndex:j] intValue]]]; }
```

The error I'm getting:

```
2012-10-02 00:42:00.266 NetSearch+DetectLocation[3741:707] 
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 
'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFNumber compare:]: nil argument'
```

Comment: Even though you can put most of the code on one line, it might be a good idea to break up your code into multiple lines so that it's easier to read.  Please list your exception as well.

Comment: I'm kind of new to this, so sorry about that, hope this is better :

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing the code that actually fills your array, its likely the array is holding a different type than you are expecting.  Try setting a breakpoint right before that line of code, and typing "po [[RSIatAddr objectAtIndex:j] class]" and see what is actually there, then you can also try your isEqualToNumber in the debug window to see if that succeeds.

I just implemented this in the AppDelegate of a new iOS App and it works:

```
NSArray *array = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithInt:0], [NSNumber numberWithInt:1], nil];
NSLog(@"%@", array);

for (NSNumber *num in array) {
    if ([num isEqualToNumber:[NSNumber numberWithInt:0]]) {
        NSLog(@"Equal");
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Not Equal");
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, I've populated my RSIatAddr from a Plist 
`NSMutableArray *RSIatAddr = [[dictionaryOfAddresses objectForKey:@"StoredAddr"]objectForKey:currentAddr];`
The values I'm populating RSIatAddr with are of type, Number. 
I know the Array is initiated properly because I printed its contents to the debugger window, and it seems fine? - any advice here?

Comment: I'm not in front of my mac to try this right now, but try wrapping the 0 constant in isEqualToNumber with an [NSNumber numberWithInt:0] or use isEqualToValue instead.

Comment: YES !  .. .  . wrapping the 0 constant with your suggestion work, Thank you once again !

Answer (score 3):

`isEqualToNumber:` takes an `NSNumber` as an argument, not the integer that you're passing.

The integer that you're using, `0`, happens to be the value of `nil`, but any integer would be extremely unlikely to be a valid pointer value for an `NSNumber`, and would also therefore crash.

Comment: still throwing the same exception after your suggested change though

Comment: @TaskinulHaque please edit your answer to include the code that continues to crash despite the fix to pass an `NSNumber` instance.